# How to disable TextBox to resize when changing the text content?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I would like to have a `TextBox` in my WPF C# application which does not change its size automatically when changing the text content with many text.

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Column="0">
                hello world</TextBox>
            <Button x:Name="button" Grid.Column="1" Click="button_Click">
                Add many Text
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  textBox.Text = "many text many text many text many text many text many text many text many text many text many text many text many text many text many text many text";
}
```

With this application, the main windows fits its size to the content by `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`. After clicking on the button the `TextBox` will resize itself and the whole window.

Is it possible to disable resizing when the text of the `TextBox` changes, but still keep the resizable property when resizing the window by the user?

Answer (score 2):

Set the MaxWidth of the TextBox to something you want?

```
 <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="0" MaxWidth="320">
            hello world
 </TextBox>
```

Where maxwidth is just my arbitrary number. This should still resize the textbox when the window is being resized.

or you can do something like this

```
 <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="0" MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=ActualWidth}">
            hello world
 </TextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your second suggestion did work for me well. With this solution the TextBox does not resize when the text is changed to something large, but the TextBox still resizes when a user changes the window size. This is exactly what I wanted. Since I am not very familiar with bindings, I would like to know what happens in the line MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=ActualWidth}"? Perhaps you can explain in more detail or give me a good link? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What the relative binding does is it listens to a value change and sets the value on its corresponding binding target. So when the user resized your Window width, it also sets the Textbox's MaxWidth to the actual width of the window.